# Apply Discount if a certain payment method selected, Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

I am trying to set a discount for a certain payment method, discount should be applied only if that method is selected, I already tried to create a cart price rule but the logic of cart price rule is not created for One step checkout.

I have two problems;

1 - Discount is being applied after the order is created, but not shown in Checkout process review page. I can see it in the order confirmation email.

2 - After going to review page if I turn back to cart, I see the discount in cart but this is not logical since the payment method is not defined any more. So discount must be taken back or should not be applied if the payment method is not selected yet, but since it is applied once after the selection of payment method Magento keeps it which is buggy in my case.

Is there any body who did such a thing with using One Step Checkout?

I also tried to control the discount on session quote by coding it myself but it also did not work since there can be other rules applied to that cart. I can not really control which one was applied and what to calculate on which amount.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

PS: I already checked all the articles and code snippets which might be helpful but none of them really solved the buggy parts as I described.

Comment: did you manage to find solution? I am on same page now as you were when you posted this question :-)

Comment: Never mind, just found it in shopping cart price rule.